# Move MySQL database files to another server from non-booting SD card

Tags: mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I need to transfer database MySQL files from one sdcard to another. I use them in my Raspberry Pi. I have one card with a working form of Raspbian. I need to transfer the files from the old SD card. The card reads no problem but the raspberry pi won't boot up . Where are the physical location of these files so I can transfer them? Or is there an easier option? I can't use the dump command because I'm not able to get into a working linux env on the old SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you need to know where you installed your MySQL server to find your database. I am on SuSE Linux and the default location is `/var/lib/mysql/{your_database_name}`. You need to move the files from here over to your other card. Your question is otherwise very confusing and you should consider posting it again with a more clear description.

Comment: That did the trick. It was hard to explain. The MySQL files were in the location you mentioned. Transferring the files with the scp command worked. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem! I always try to help with any question.